# iOS Paypal response id i don't take

Tags: ios

Hello I'm using paypal sdk with Xcode , iOS

Everything works success but i want to take response id how can i add this response id to my NSString value. please help me I'm writing my output.

My Codes

```
(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
NSLog(@"PayPal Payment Success!");
self.resultText = [completedPayment description];


kod = [completedPayment description];


NSLog (@" \n\n\n\nDesc = %@\n\n\n  ",kod);
```

Output

```
CurrencyCode: USD
Amount: 43.45
Short Description: Surprise
Intent: sale
Processable: Already processed
Display: $43.45
Confirmation: {
    client =     {
        environment = sandbox;
        "paypal_sdk_version" = "2.1.2";
        platform = iOS;
        "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";
    };
    response =     {
        "create_time" = "2014-06-20T11:15:56Z";
        id = "PAY-2G6302017M038104YKOSBP3A";
        intent = sale;
        state = approved;
    };
    "response_type" = payment;
}
Details: Subtotal: 28, Shipping: 12, Tax: 3.45
BN code: (null)
Item: '{1|Surprise|28.00|USD|SALE-1244}'
```

i need with NSString create_time and id

ex :

NSString *createtime = etc..
NSString *id = etc...

Im working about 2-3 hours i didn't do

please help me.

Best Regards

I DID Working codes

```
NSDictionary *dicpayments = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:completedPayment.confirmation[@"response"]];
NSString *paymentKey = [dicpayments objectForKey:@"id" ];
NSString *createdTime = [dicpayments objectForKey:@"create_time" ];
```

Thanks for idea dude ;)

Comment: What kind of object is `completedPayment`?

Comment: i added look at codes

Comment: `completedPayment` class hasn't properties to retrieve them? Seems like there is a dictionary inside dictionary to retrieve `creation_date` and `id`.

Comment: im newbie all codes here dude, give me codes i will try

Comment: any help ? idea ? i think need array codes ?

Comment: Still, where did you get (source/doc) of `PayPalPayment`?

Comment: Dude i need only array codes .  kod variable gives too many output i need only array codes. I'm showing output i think easy for knows objective c arrays. all codes and output here and working success

Comment: Yeah, but if it developped correctly, maybe completedPayment.confirmation[@"response"] exists..

Comment: YES CODES HERE    #pragma mark Proof of payment validation

- (void)sendCompletedPaymentToServer:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
    // TODO: Send completedPayment.confirmation to server
    NSLog(@"Here is your proof of payment:\n\n%@\n\nSend this to your server for confirmation and fulfillment.", completedPayment.confirmation);
}

Comment: Larme i added new codes will works just i need now create_time and id codes ;) please write look at main question

Comment: Then, try [[completedPayment.confirmation objectForKey:@"response"] objectForKey:@"create_date"] and  [[completedPayment.confirmation objectForKey:@"response"] objectForKey:@"id"]

Comment: @user This is a very, very low-quality question by Stackoverflow standards. Basically it boils down to give-me-teh-codez. Aside from that, poor formatting, poorly written. Please read [faq] and [ask] for information on how to write a good question. Also, you are probably a hair's breadth away from an automatic ban.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 If kid is giving you 
desc = {
    "create_time" = "2014-06-20T11:52:06Z";
    id = "PAY-1J490299FR6951927KOSCAZQ";
    intent = sale;
    state = approved;
}
Then just use 
   NSDictionary *dicpayments = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:completedPayment.confirmation[@"response"]];
```

NSString *paymentKey = [dicpayments objectForKey:@"id" ];
NSString *createdTime = [dicpayments objectForKey:@"create_time" ];

Comment: yes gives me that but i need inside it id and create time codes ;)

Comment: NSDictionary *dicpayment = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[ kod objectForKey:@"Desc"]];

     NSString *paymentKey = [dicpayment objectForKey:@"id" ];
     NSString *createdTime = [dicpayment objectForKey:@"create_time" ]; use this code

Comment: user366358 thanks for idea i changed your code and works ;) edit your post and add my last code i will approve your post with tick